# If-statement comparing two values, one of them double digit

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I´m having a weird error in my vba program that compares the size of two values from textboxes.
The code goes as follows:

```
If TextBoxValue1.Value < TextBoxValue2.Value Then
    MsgBox "Value 2 is not allowed to be bigger than Value 1!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Now this works perfectly fine as long as I´m typing in single digit values. But as soon Value 1 is double digit (e.g. 10) and Value 2 is single digit (e.g. 9), the MsgBox pops up, even though Value 1 is bigger than Value 2.
Is there anything I´m missing?

Comment: Textbox values are *strings* - if you want them to act like numbers you need to use (eg) `CDbl()` or `CLng()` to convert them to numeric values.

Comment: Its not a weird error, its your lack of understanding.  The result returned from textbox.value is a string, so you are comparing two strings, not two numbers.  Convert your strings to numbers (e.g. Clng) and your code will work as you expect.

Comment: @freeflow the truth hurts sometimes haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `VAL()` function to make them number values. Try-

```
If Val(TextBox1) < Val(TextBox2) Then
    MsgBox "Value 2 is not allowed to be bigger than Value 1!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Note that Val only recognize the . as decimal separator.  If a different separator is used (international settings?) you might want to use CDbl or your own conversion function.